# Voltage Fluctuations in Arduino-opamp-thermistor circuit

Tags: adc, noise, thermistor, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm working on a board that takes measurements of voltage off a thermistor through an Arduino and amplified by an opamp (really an instrumentation amp [AD623](http://www.me.psu.edu/sommer/me445/AD623.pdf)), also there are two potentiometers. See [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEaRc.jpg) below:
[image]

I've been receiving some very strange voltage fluctuations that I can't seem to isolate to any particular component. I've tested both the voltage source and the thermistor independently of the circuit and they are both stable.

Below is a graph

[image]

..and on the bottom of the pic you can see the fluctuations over time with no change implemented in the system. At times they look almost oscillatory, but then stabilize at a random voltage before jumping around again. example, would go from 0.01-0.06 volts, jump around 0.3-0.4 volts, and occasionally go as high as 1-2 volts (With no change to the thermistor!)

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for what is causing the noise/fluctuations. Also, I've heard of a floating ground (not sure what that is), and I was wondering if that was an issue here.

Comment: Show a real schematic, particularly of the analog front end.  What you have is a wiring diagram at best.  No, I'm not going dig out the datasheet for that chip to see which pins are which, even if I could read the chip name.  Also, what is the graph of?  What point of the circuit?  What was the power supply doing at that time.  What else was going on then?

Comment: Since temperature is a very slow-changing magnitude, go ahead and add two capacitors between pins 2 and 4, and between pins 3 and 4, of your AD623. As close as possible to the pins of the IC. Ideally, ceramic (you can find with 10 uF). Or even two sets of capacitors, each being a 47 uF (or so) electrolytic in parallel with a small 100 nF ceramic. That will reduce your input noise. I don't know what's your setup, and how long your wires are. Tell us if your measured signal (whatever it is :)) gets better.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best thing to give you for the chip would be, but maybe these pics will help.
http://i1149.photobucket.com/albums/o599/ktizzlewat/OpAmpDiagram.png
http://i1149.photobucket.com/albums/o599/ktizzlewat/OpAmpPins.png

As for the graph it just shows our voltage vs. time (a measurement taken every 300ms) and I was just including it because it was the only graph of the data I've made so far. 

Nothing else was really going on at the time...

Comment: the power was stable at 5.072 volts, basically I just let the entire device just sit. 

@Telaclavo
I'll definitely try those things and get back

Comment: Time to give up.

Comment: 300 ms is such a long sampling period, that your weird graph might be due to aliasing. Any frequency higher than 1.7 Hz (!) present in your input wires will be folded back into your 0 to 1.7 Hz band, showing up as useful signal. You have to knock out out-of-band noise, low-pass filtering the input signals, and the capacitors I mentioned go in that direction. // It could be other reasons. This is just one thing to discard.

Comment: Correctmundo @Telaclavo, THe student has to learn EMC management by making high gain linear amps stable. This one is probably oscillating at 1MHz with a wire wound pot on the gain control.  Keeping all parts within a 1" radius and sending the thermistor on twisted pair to remote 10~15 turns /in should resolve help. Then add V+ decoupling with a small ferrite choke, not to mention a current limiting resistor for the IR LED. Whats the confusion about?